# Can scholarship grantees take their children?

Tags: italy

What procedures and documents are required to take our 1-year-old child to Italy with us? My wife and I both are applying for a master’s scholarship.

We are from Afghanistan.

Comment: What research have you done up to now? Eg https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home.aspx

Comment: @Traveller i checked the given link.. it says nothing about a scholarship grantee.

Comment: The webpage says nothing about "scholarship grantee" because  "scholarship grantee" is not a visa class. Try instead using one of the "Study" (in Italian: _Studio_) links, as college or university work leading to a Master's Degree is considered "Studying."

Answer (score 5):

If you are simply asking about the effects of having a scholarship, it doesn't matter. For visa purposes you are treated exactly the same as any other student. You should apply for a study visa in the normal way. You tell them about the scholarship as part of explaining how you finance your studies (once you have the scholarship).

You are normally permitted to take dependents such as spouses and children with you when you study, but you will need to make applications for them.